# GridView overlapping effect

Tags: c#, gridview, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a GridView with grouped data.

All is like in Grouped Items Page template in VS2012 except I set more data then they do there (around 15 groups, around 200 items total).

All is fine except strange overlapping effect in the middle of page. It's not always on same place. When scrolling this overlapping area can move to other groups.

[image: Here is a [screenshot][1].]

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce same problem in the project I just created using Grid App project template in VS2012. 
I copied my DataSource object there and all worked fine until I did one small thing - set HidesIfEmpty="True" for GroupStyle of the GridView.

Incredible but this small option which should help us hiding empty groups makes this strange overlapping effect.

Answer (score 0):

I bet this is because you nest ScrollViewers - perhaps put multiple GridViews in a ScrollViewer or a "master GridView".

Comment: I don't use any ScrollViewer on that page.

Comment: No. All is exactly same as in Grouped Items Page template in VS2012 except many items and HidesIfEmpty="True" as I described below. As I finally found out last is the reason of this effect.

Comment: Interesting. It sounds like a bug worth reporting to Microsoft (if you want it fixed in the future that is).

Comment: Oh, it seems like you already [reported it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/648f9f34-22d1-49c3-90fc-8711ba1ecd82). Cool. :)

Comment: Yes. Will see how that will help. Anyway thanks for your tries to help.